# Problem updating wordpress

Tags: wordpress

A problems occurs when I am trying to update my WordPress 3.0 to WordPress 3.0.1 using "Update Automatically" button of update-core page. I am getting a message like below:

> Downloading update from http://wordpress.org/wordpress-3.0.1.zip…

And everything is stopped after this message. What to do now?

Comment: Maybe wait a couple days for Wordpress Answers to come out of beta and ask there :)  http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1500/wordpress-answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three main things to check:

- Do you have enough free space?
- Are the permissions correct?
- If you log into the web server can it download the file using wget or similar?

If the hosting is provided by a third party they may have altered the permissions (often by accident) or limited downloads.

Comment: I have enough space, permissions are correct (because I already updated plugins and themes). I can update WordPress by using normal download and delete-reload all contents. But by that procedure all my contents (blogs, themes and edits of themes, plugins and edit of plugins) will be deleted.

Comment: Without a readout of the error.log file from Apache to help diagnose the problem further looks like you'll be left with the extended upgrade guide http://codex.wordpress.org/Upgrading_WordPress_Extended#Step_10:_Update_Permalinks_and_.htaccess

Comment: @chanchal1987 if you have console access, you may want to consider moving to the SVN method of maintaining WordPress.  This keeps your local files in place while upgrading the core WP files:  http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing/Updating_WordPress_with_Subversion  Most of the plugins have SVN repositories that you can update from too.